# Stripe on codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I have stripe in a codeigniter project and I have followed [Link 1](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#metadata) and [Link 2](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial). 
I am working on lamp Apache 2.4 and Ubuntu 14 L.T.S

However, I keep getting Not found 404.Seems that the route is not being picked up by the server.
I have carefully reviewed my controllers and views but cannot find anything wrong.

The pay method inside the Payment class is:

```
public function pay(){

  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_somekey");

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer@example.com',
      'source'  => $token

  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(

      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd'

  ));
  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
}
```

And my form inside my view goes like:

```
<?php require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); ?>

<form action="Payment/pay" method="post">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="pk_test_some_key"
          data-description="Access for a year"
          data-amount="5000"
          data-locale="auto">
 </script>
</form>
```

I'm using composer so the config file was modified as:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Apache spits out:

```
The requested URL /Payment/pay was not found on this server.
```

Any pointers are much welcome.

EDIT: The routes.php looks like:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'payment';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: What if you try `<form action="/Payment/pay" method="post">` or `<form action="<?php echo base_url('payment/pay') ?>" method="post">`?

Comment: @TheDrot, the first one I have already tried, the second one gives back an error

Comment: Second one probably gives error because you're not loading url helper. In whatever method you use to load form view use `$this->load->helper('url')`.

Comment: oh yeah ur right I forgot the helper, but still the route is not found by Apache

Comment: Is controller filename `Payment.php` with capital first letter, same with class name?

Comment: yup! they both are with capitals.

Comment: Then most likely something is wrong with routes config, can't really help you without seeing it.

Comment: do you mean the config on my apache server? or the app folder routes? I have edited the post to include the .config routes.php file...

Comment: Ok, does it work if you try `<form action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/payment/pay') ?>" method="post">`?

Comment: I actually did a var dump on the token and realized it was not passing, I'm getting NULL, when doing:
       ``$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
         var_dump($token);``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and wanted to share it.

Make sure your code has got:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

If you have `.htaaccess` make sure it can load without `index.php` for every request. In my case I had something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/  [L]
```

Which, for whatever reason did not help so I ended up removing it and leaving `index.php` on the routes, I know, it's ugly.

Finally I added `index.php` to the form's action route as suggested and it worked.

Hope it can help someone.

Credits and thanks to @TheDrot for pointing it out.